# how to correct a crooked joint of brick veneer and drywall

Tags: brick

Installed brick veneer around a fireplace but failed to put a guideline where it met the gype wall.  The line is slightly crooked... any ideas to hide this?  If I rip out the bricks on the edge and reset them in a straight line, I'm wondering if the mortar will have a different color than the rest of the wall given that it comes from another batch.
[image]

Comment: Could you put up a couple more photos for a better perspective? At least one with a level, straight-on view.

Comment: Put a quarter-round trim on it, nailing to the sheetrock.

Comment: i ended up ripping out some of the bricks from the top and bottom and resetting them closer to the middle ones.  Will put in the mortar on the weekend and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled some of the bricks off from the bottom and the top and reset them to give it a more even appearance.  There wasn't any problem with the mortar being from different batches, you can't tell once it is dry.